# Deactivate a region of range slider

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to show on my range slider 0 to 300 but only allow the user to select from 80 to 300

```dart
RangeSlider(
  min: 0.0,
  max: 300.0,
  divisions: 10,
  labels: RangeLabels(
    _startValue.round().toString(),
    _endValue.round().toString(),
  ),
  values: RangeValues(_startValue, _endValue),
  onChanged: (values) {
    setState(() {
      _startValue = values.start;
      _endValue = values.end;
    });
  },
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check start value on `onChanged` and stop user from going <80.

```dart
onChanged: (values) {
  if (values.start < 80) return;
  setState(() {
    _startValue = values.start;
    _endValue = values.end;
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just import
`import 'dart:math';` and then use `min` and `max` functions to limit the values:

```dart
onChanged: (values) {
  setState(() {
    _startValue = max(values.start, 80);
    _endValue = min(values.end, 250); // If you also want to limit the upper value
  });
},
```

Comment: does this impact performance compared to @Yeasin answer. ?

Comment: I dont' know why it should. `min` and `max` are basic functions. I'm using it in other context and haven't experienced any performance degradation

Comment: yes but it rebuilds because of setState i’ve upvoted anyway as I find your answer elegant thank you 

Comment: ah you mean that it rebuilds the slider even when the value does not change? Yeah that might be true. But still, shouldn't impact performance as that only happens when a user taps the slider and that shouldn't happen so often that it has bad influence

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you could use if..else to make it happen.

```dart
onChanged: (value) {
                if((value)<=80){
                  setState(() {
                    _startValue = 80;
                  });
                }
              },
```